# How to throw error message in antd upload component?

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, components, antd

I'm using antd upload component, currently I using it for image upload,  I try to validate it with max allowed size. if uploaded image size exceeds the acceptable limit means, i need to throw error message like. "please upload image less than 5mb". my code is,

```
                                     <Form.Item
                                        name={
                                          "messageImage" + broadcastSession
                                        }
                                        rules={[
                                          {
                                            required: true,
                                            message:
                                              "Please upload an image",
                                          },
                                        ]}
                                        hasFeedback
                                      >
                                        <Upload
                                          beforeUpload={(uploadedImage) => {
                                            return (
                                              uploadedImage.size >
                                              // size in bytes
                                            5242880 &&
                                              true
                                            );
                                          }}
                                          showUploadList={false}
                                          listType="picture"
                                          maxCount={1}
                                          accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
                                          onChange={handleImageUpload}
                                        >
                                          <Space>
                                            <Button
                                              icon={<UploadOutlined />}
                                            >
                                              Choose Image
                                            </Button>
                                          </Space>
                                        </Upload>
                                      </Form.Item>
```

1. I need to throw error message like. "please upload image less than 5mb", if uploaded image size exceeds.
2. Form should not submit.

Answer (score 0):

define a `beforeUpload` function like this. `message` is imported from `antd`

```
function beforeUpload(file) {
 
  const isLt1M = file.size < MAX_FILE_SIZE;
  if (!isLt1M) {
    message.error('Please upload image less than 5mb');
  }
  return isJpgOrPng;
}
```

Put it in the antd `Upload` component

```
.
.
<Upload
  beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
  showUploadList={false}
.
.
```